# linked gradle project Nothing to show

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have installed Android Studio **`3.0`**,`gradle` 4.4 on my mac.
and I created a new android project , it can not build ,

> Error:Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

I tried to set the `gradle` , but  it say nothing to show.
like this

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: your gradle is 2.3.3 may be you should update your gradle to 4.4

Comment: I had installed gradle 4.4WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Gradle 4.4

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-12-06 09:05:06 UTC
Revision:     cf7821a6f79f8e2a598df21780e3ff7ce8db2b82

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          9.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 9.0.1+11)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.12.3 x86_64

Answer (score 0):

you need to upgrade your **gradle** to 4.4 because android studio version 3.0.0+ needs 4.1+ **gradle** see more details at

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

I gave up at last.
I delete the Android Studio completely , and installed version 2.3.
Still have some problem , but it can work now.
Advise for freshers like me :use the stable version, there is no need to try the latest version, it will waste you a lots of time ,and you get nothing.